# Golang JSON Unmarshal multiple calls

Tags: json, struct, go

I'm writing an API wrapper where a call to the API returns a json response of some data, lets say:

```
{
    group_id: 123,
    group_name: "cool kids",
}
```

for the url `example.com/api/groups`

You can then append `fields=members` to the url (so something like: `example.com/api/groups?group_id=123&fields=members`) to then get:

```
{
    members: [...some data..]
}
```

Note how the other fields are now missing...

<s>Well I'm trying to use a single `struct` which would look like:</s>

```
type Club struct {
    GroupId int `json:"group_id"`
    GroupName string `json:"group_name"`
    Members []struct {...} `json:"members"
}
```

This is what the structs look like:

```
type Committee struct {
    GroupId     string `json:"group_id"`
    GroupName   string `json:"group_name"`
    Members     []struct {
        Person     Person  `json:"person"`
        Rank       float64 `json:"rank"`
        Side       string  `json:"side"`
        Title      string  `json:"title"`
    } `json:"members"`
}

type Person struct {
    id     string `json:"id"`
    name   string `json:"name"`
    age    int    `json:"age"`
}

func getGroup() Club {...}
func (c *Club) GetMembers() {...}
```

So I make the first call which unmarshals using `getGroup` so the struct has `GroupId` and `GroupName` just fine and `Members` is empty because the call didn't return anything for it.

I then call `club.GetMembers()` to populate the `Members` field so that the entire struct would be populated but it doesn't seem to be extracting it into the struct because at the end `Members` is still empty and the data for `GroupId` and `GroupName` is still there.

I know for sure that the call is returning what I'm expecting so I figure it's `Unmarshal` that isn't working so how would I go about this? Is this not within the functionality of `Unmarshal`?

**EDIT**
I just pushed the exact code to github, still unsure.

This is the repo: https://github.com/PeteJodo/gosun

This is a gist using the above repo: https://gist.github.com/PeteJodo/d5335b9f66304148483b

The main files of concern:

[service.go](https://github.com/PeteJodo/gosun/blob/master/service.go)

[congress.go](https://github.com/PeteJodo/gosun/blob/master/congress/congress.go)

[committees.go](https://github.com/PeteJodo/gosun/blob/master/congress/committees.go)

[legislators.go](https://github.com/PeteJodo/gosun/blob/master/congress/legislators.go)

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/uuO8iGh2Uo < it works fine, are you sure you're using a pointer?

Comment: Sorry something busy came up. I'll try to answer everyone. go version: `go version go1.4.1 darwin/amd64` I'll add more info when I get the chance. Also it looks like it's working for you OneOfOne hmm. This was example code, I'll post the actual code shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so my issue has nothing to do with `Unmarshal` per say. What was happening was that the API response returns:

```
{
   results: [{
          group_id: 123,
          group_name: "cool kids"
       }, ...],
   ...
}
```

...each result being an individual group. My problem was that each group was it's own struct and I had a method for the `Group` struct that would make the next call to expand its `Members` field, and I was using the `Group` struct as the destination for `Unmarshal` instead of something like `Results` which would be structured correctly for the API response and THEN extract the correct `Group` and its `Members` field